# Pass query string and stop RadWindow from reloading on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radwindow

First I realize this issue has been discussed before however none of the solutions appear to be working for me and instead of reviving an ancient post I wanted to make a new one.

I am using button embedded in a RadGrid CommandItemTemplate to launch a RadWindow from codebehind. I am doing this in codebehind so that I may pass a query string to my new radwindow for some further processing. My issue is that I can close the radwindow and refresh the page and have the previously closed radwindow re-open. I have a RadWindowManager set up with EnableViewState = false as has been suggested before however this is not solving my issue. I have also read that setting the VisibleOnPageLoad property of the RadWindow to false will stop it from reloading on postback, however this also stops it from loading at all in my code. My code is as follows.

Command Item Template:

```
<CommandItemTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="ButtonONE" Text="Add New" runat="server" CommandName="AddNew"></asp:Button>
</CommandItemTemplate>
```

Rad Window Manager:

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManagerOne" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <Windows>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

Code Behind:

```
 protected void grdOne_ItemCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandName == "AddNew") {
            RadWindow newWindow = new RadWindow();
            newWindow.NavigateUrl = "AddEdit.aspx";
            newWindow.Skin = "Web20";
            newWindow.Title = "Add/Edit";
            newWindow.Modal = true;
            newWindow.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
            newWindow.DestroyOnClose = true;
            //newWindow.Behaviors = Close, Move;
            newWindow.EnableViewState = false;
            newWindow.AutoSize = true;
            newWindow.VisibleStatusbar = false;
            newWindow.DestroyOnClose = true;
            RadWindowManagerOne.Windows.Add(newWindow);
        }
  }
```

Any Assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Did it work?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I ended up utilizing javascript to launch the radwindow which allowed me to avoid the postbacks. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should **not** set VisibleOnPageLoad = True if you don't want to show the RadWindow after postback.

What you probably need to do is after you create the RadWindow then register a startup script where you $find the radWindow client object and call its show() method:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/radwindowobject/defaultcs.aspx

You may also check this demo: [Edit dialog for RadGrid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window)

Comment: You should not even need to create a new object on the server, because you can create one on the client: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening.html which can even let you avoid the postback if you get the needed parameters with JS.

Answer (score 0):

When reloading a page that has already been POST-ed, the browser asks you to resend the information and if you confirm/continue, the last postback is initiated again, so the method to open the radWindow is called again. You can confirm this by placing a breakpoint in it.
A trick to avoid such behavior is possible.

Add an hidden field in your page:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="_repostcheckcode" />
```

in code behind add the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancelUnexpectedRePost();
}

private void CancelUnexpectedRePost()
{
    string clientCode = _repostcheckcode.Value;

    //Get Server Code from session (Or Empty if null)
    string serverCode = Session["_repostcheckcode"] as string  ?? "";

    if (!IsPostBack || clientCode.Equals(serverCode))
    {
        //Codes are equals - The action was initiated by the user
        //Save new code (Can use simple counter instead Guid)
        string code = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();  
        _repostcheckcode.Value = code;
        Session["_repostcheckcode"] = code;
    }
    else
    {
        //Unexpected action - caused by F5 (Refresh) button
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319955/How-to-prevent-Re-Post-action-caused-by-pressing-b) you find the original article about how to solve the above issue.
Another reference for you on how to open a radWindow can be taken from one of my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043158/open-dialog-window-on-checkbox-click-in-telerik-radgrid/29046414#29046414).

Concerning how to pass your parameters to the window, I would use a standard approach simply calling a class from Page_Load of the window you open which will make available the parameters you need.

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string MyMethod()
    {
      string myString;
       //your logic
      return myString;
     }
 }
```